# A map to a larger dimensional space is not surjective

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reading Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right book and its my first time doing linear algebra. I'm confused on this proof: 
Suppose V and W are finite-dimensional vector spaces such that
dim V < dim W. Then no linear map from V to W is surjective.
Proof:
Let T ∈ L(V, W).
Then
dim range T = dim V - dim null T 
≤ dim V
< dim W
I understand the first equality (fundamental thm of linear maps). the last inequality i understand comes from the assumption. I'm confused on the middle inequality. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dimension of the null space is weakly greater than $0$. $ a - k \leq a$ if $k \geq 0$.

Comment: i.e., dimension is nonnegative.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, if $x$ and $y$ are numbers and $y$ is nonnegative, meaning $y\geq0$, then $x-y\leq x$.

In this case, $\dim\mathrm{null}\;T\geq 0$, so
$\dim V - \dim\mathrm{null}\;T \leq \dim V$.